# fabricjs label on hover

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I try to add label when user hover element:

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    originX: 'top',
    originY: 'top',
    width: 150,
    height: 120,
    fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
    transparentCorners: true
});
var text = new fabric.Text('hello world', {
    fontSize: 30,
    originX: 'top',
    originY: 'top'
});

canvas.on('mouse:over', function(e) {
    var group = new fabric.Group([ rect, text ], {
    left: e.target.left,
    top: e.target.top
});
    canvas.add(group);
    canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('mouse:out', function(e) {
    //e.target.set('fill', 'green');
    canvas.remove(group);
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

But when `mouse:out` fires i get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: group is not defined
    at i.<anonymous> (can.js:38)
    at i.r (fabric.min.js:1)
    at i._fireOverOutEvents (fabric.min.js:3)
    at i.findTarget (fabric.min.js:3)
    at i.__onMouseMove (fabric.min.js:4)
    at i._onMouseMove (fabric.min.js:4)
```

How can i make a group global with left and top of hovered element, or there is a better way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group` is scoped as a private variable local to the `mouse:over` event. Try 
removing `var` from:

```js
var group = new fabric.Group([ rect, text ], {
```

to scope `group` globally:

```js
 group = new fabric.Group([ rect, text ], {
```

Answer (score 2):

**DEMO**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    originX: 'top',
    originY: 'top',
    width: 150,
    height: 120,
    fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
    
});
var text = new fabric.Text('hello world', {
    fontSize: 30,
    originX: 'top',
    originY: 'top'
});
var group = new fabric.Group([ rect, text ], {
     left: 0,
     top: 0,
     selectable : false,
     visible: false,
});
canvas.add(group);
canvas.renderAll();

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(e) {
    var p = canvas.getPointer(e.e);
    group.set({
     left: p.x,
     top: p.y,
     visible: true
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('mouse:out', function(e) {
    group.set({
     visible: false
    })
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border:2px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.17/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='c' width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

You no need to create group on every mouse over, you just set `visible: true/false,` so according to this it will visible. Check DEMO.